# Enforcing maximum number of relations for a record

Tags: postgresql, transaction, concurrency, isolation-level

I am trying to figure out the way to enforce a maximum number of relations in a highly concurrent system.  The following is an example use case.

```
// Job table
job_id   | ... | num_positions
xx-xx-xx | ... | 3

// Positions table - only 1 spot left
position_id | job_id   | user_id
aa-aa-aa    | xx-xx-xx | ee-ee-ee
bb-bb-bb    | xx-xx-xx | ff-ff-ff
```

Now let's say two people try to fill the last spot at the same time. What is the best/right way to enforce that there will only ever be a maximum of 3 records? Ideally, the transaction that fires first fills the spot. What is the best way to implement this sort of functionality? Isolation levels etc?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *two people try to fill the last spot at the same time.* By two concurrent and independent INSERTs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about

```
// Positions table - 3 spots for `xx-xx-xx` job, only 1 spot is free
position_id | job_id   | user_id
------------+----------+---------
aa-aa-aa    | xx-xx-xx | ee-ee-ee    -- used spot
bb-bb-bb    | xx-xx-xx | ff-ff-ff    -- used spot
cc-cc-cc    | xx-xx-xx | NULL        -- free spot
```

The amount of spot rows per a job is equal to `jobs.num_positions` for according `job_id` value. They're created with according amount when the row is inserted into `jobs` table or when `jobs` table is updated and `amount` value for some job(s) is increased.

While user filling a spot users's `id` inserts to the `user_id` column. When user frees a spot its `user_id` value is updated to NULL back.

All operations are performed only by UPDATE queries. Spot filling query includes `WHERE job_id = @job AND user_id IS NULL LIMIT 1`.

If two concurrent users try to fill a spot the user which do this earlier will fill whereas the user who tries to do this later will fail because there is no record which matches the conditions `WHERE job_id = @job AND user_id IS NULL`.

Comment: Further more you can maintain the list automatically with triggers. Block insert and delete operations that would change the number of rows on the `position` table by rasing an error from a trigger, use triggers on the `job` table to manage rows in `position` when a job is added/deleted or `num_positions` is updated, raising errors if there are too many to support a reduction in num_positions. You'll need to make sure that the changes made to `position` by the triggers on `job` don't trip the errors on modification in those triggers.